# Prevent readline line submit

Tags: libreadline

I'm using readline in an application that follows the input realtime. I don't want to allow the user to press Enter, Control + J, or any other equivalent, and thus unintentionally clearing the field.

I'm actually forwarding the keys myself, so I can catch and prevent certain key inputs, but I don't think this is the way to go because reverse search (Control - R) must also be handled.

I've looked over the gnu docs, but haven't found anything useful.

My code is similar to this https://github.com/ulfalizer/readline-and-ncurses

Comment: I'm no expert, but does anything in the [Alternative Interface](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/readline/rlman_41.html) help?

Comment: Thanks for the link, unfortunately not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inhibit this keys configuring key bindings in the initialization file of libreadline :

1. in `~/.inputrc` to configure for current user
2. in `/etc/inputrc` to configure for all users.

To inhibit <kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Control+J</kbd>, you could add to the initialization file :

> RETURN:
>    C-J:

If you prefer you can do this programmatically using [rl_unbind_key](http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/rlman_2.html), adding to your code :

```
rl_unbind_key('\r'); // unbind Enter
rl_unbind_key('\n'); // unbind Control+J
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks!